# TypeError in when storing data in array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use [fetch-jsonp](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp) to get some data from the darksky api, but when i fetch the data i get a TypeError when storing the data

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          daily: [],
          hourly: [],
          hourlySum: '',
          dailySum: '',
          loading: true,
          error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator.geolocation){
      function success(position) {

        var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var results = fetchJsonp(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/key/`+latitude+`,`+longitude+`?units=auto`)
        .then(result => {
          this.setState({
            daily: result.daily.data,
            hourly: result.hourly.data,
            hourlySum: result.hourly,
            dailySum: result.daily,
            loading: false,
            error: null
          });
        })/*.catch(err => {
            // Something went wrong. Save the error in state and re-render.
            this.setState({
              loading: false,
              error: err
            });
          });*/
      };
      function error() {
        console.log( 'geolocation error' )
      };
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success.bind(this), error);
    }
  }
```

The error message is TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined referencing `daily: result.daily.data` but since i defined `daily` as an array i dont understand why i get a TypeError
[This](https://darksky.net/dev/docs/forecast) is the response format for reference

I did the same thing using Axios (which worked) but because of CORS i switched to JSONP.

My working Axios code looked like

```
var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = axios.get(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/key/`+latitude+`,`+longitude+`?units=auto`)
    .then(result => {
      _this.setState({
        daily: result.data.daily.data,
        hourly: result.data.hourly.data,
        hourlySum: result.data.hourly,
        dailySum: result.data.daily,
        loading: false,
        error: null
      });
    })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see where you're defining `daily` as an array. You're grabbing some data from over the wire and it appears that data does not have a proper named `daily`. Basically, `result.daily` appears to be undefined. Try logging out `result` and verify you're getting the data you expect.

Comment: The daily array is defined in the constructor. I also updated my question since i had it working with axios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp website:

```
Make JSONP request like window.fetch
```

That means you'll need to call `response.json()`, as required for `fetch`.

See a sample from that page you linked:

```
fetchJsonp('/users.jsonp')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  }).catch(function(ex) {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
  })
```

So before you call `setState` chain another `then()` with a call to `response.json()`

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected :)